# DirectX11) Is it possible to use "Negative Index" in the Texture2D resource?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, hlsl

I'm new to DirectX, graphics, and HLSL and I have seen some weird code in the example below :

```
Texture2D       g_BaseTexture   : register(t0); // It may be used in the second argument in GaussianSample function

static float Gaussian5x5[25] =
{
    0.003765f, 0.015019f, 0.023792f, 0.015019f, 0.003765f,
    0.015019f, 0.059912f, 0.094907f, 0.059912f, 0.015019f,
    0.023792f, 0.094907f, 0.150342f, 0.094907f, 0.023792f,
    0.015019f, 0.059912f, 0.094907f, 0.059912f, 0.015019f,
    0.003765f, 0.015019f, 0.023792f, 0.015019f, 0.003765f
};

float GaussianSample(int2 UV, Texture2D Tex)
{
    float4  Output = (float4)0.f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {

            int2    ConvertUV = UV + int2(i - 2, j - 2); // Convert UV can be (x,y) = (-2, -2)
            Output += Tex[ConvertUV] * Gaussian5x5[i * 5 + j];
        }
    }

    return Output.x;
}
```

In this nested loop, ConvertUV can be (x,y) = (-2, -2). If then, **It access to the "Tex" which is the Texture2D type resource using negative Index. I think negative indexing is invalid** but If I test like this, there is no error or crash at all :

```
int2 Temp = int2(-2, -2);
float4 TempOutput = Tex[Temp];
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing resource out of bounds is guaranteed to return zero. See here:
[Accessing Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-cs-access).

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it :)